# Summary prototype and if structures

Tags: c++, function, prototype, function-prototypes

So I need to create a function that will turn the COUT part ONLY of each "if" statement:

```
// Respond to the user's menu selection
if (choice == ADULT_CHOICE)
    {
        charges = months * ADULT; 
        cout << over3 << "The total charges are $" << charges << endl; 
    }
else if (choice == CHILD_CHOICE)
    {
        charges = months * CHILD;
        cout << over3 << "The total charges are $" << charges << endl; 
    }
else if (choice == SENIOR_CHOICE)
    {
        charges = months * SENIOR;              
        cout << over3 << "The total charges are $" << charges << endl; 
    }
```

Into a summary function that reads like [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGAr2.jpg).

So far I have made a total mess of the code and I really need some help... here is what I have so far but most of it is probably not salvageable:

function prototype:

```
int summary(string, int, int, double);
```

Main:

```
    //variables
    int choice;         // menu choice
    int months;         //number of months
    double charges;     //monthly charges
    string type1 = "Adult", type2 = "Child", type3 = "Senior";


if (choice == ADULT_CHOICE)
        {
            charges = months * ADULT; 
            cout << summary(type1, months, 40, charges);
        }
        else if (choice == CHILD_CHOICE)
        {
            charges = months * CHILD;
           cout << summary(type2, months, 20, charges);
        }
        else if (choice == SENIOR_CHOICE)
        {
            charges = months * SENIOR;              
            cout << summary(type3, months, 30, charges);
        }
```

function definition:

```
int summary(string type, int months, int price , double charges)
{

system("CLS");
cout << down7;
cout << over3 << "    Summary of Charges    \n"
     << over3 << "----------------------------\n"
     << over3 << "Membership Type:   " << type << endl;
cout << over3 << "Number of Months:  " << months << endl;
cout << over3 << "Membership Prices: " << price << endl;
cout << over3 << "Total of Charges:  " << charges << endl;
}
```

I know there is a lot wrong here and I just needed some help going in the right direction. I have no idea how to solve the string variable stuff, should I keep going that route? or go an other way entirely?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It looks like there is a much cleaner and very textbook solution to this problem using OOP instead of a giant switch statement.  Also, your `summary` function prototypes don't match.

Comment: What's the problem with the code as you've written it?

Comment: What is the string problem?

Comment: @Aggieboy Im not sure what OOP is or how to use it. and what do you mean by switch statement? Yeah I realize that they do not match, NOt sure how to define the type though to mean multiple selections.

Comment: @user3470987 Look up virtual methods and inheritance.  It is not a simple concept and learning OOP (object oriented programming) will take some time (especially C++'s version), but it will trivialize many problems like this one.

Comment: But in any case, I have no idea what the actual issue is that you are having.  We need something to tell us why you think/know your code is not working.  What is the expected output, and what is the actual output?

Comment: OKay I edited some parts of it. So when I run this, it wont display this part of the program. It will do the first part (not in question), but not the part in the summary

Answer (score 0):

There are several designs and implementations for your requirements.

**switch statement**
Instead of all these `if-else-if` in a ladder, use a `switch` statement.  I believe a `switch` statement would be more readable:

```
double rate = 0.0;
std::string type_name;
double price = 0.0;
switch (choice)
{
  case ADULT_CHOICE:
    rate = adult_rate;
    type_name = "Adult";
    price = 40;
    break;
  case CHILD_CHOICE:
    rate = child_rate;
    type_name = "Child";
    price = 20;
    break;
  case SENIOR_CHOICE:
    rate = senior_rate;
    type_name = "Senior";
    price = 30;
    break;
  default:
    cerr << "Invalid ticket type\r\n";
    exit(1);
}
charges = months * rate;
summary(type_name, months, price, charges);
```

**Look up table**
A more maintainable design and implementation is to use a look up table.  Create a table of entries that contain information about a ticket.  (This will lead up to the last design consideration).

```
struct Ticket
{
  unsigned int choice;
  char const * type_name;
  double       price;
  double       rate;
};

const Ticket ticket_info[] =
{
  {ADULT_CHOICE, "Adult", 40, ADULT_RATE},
  {CHILD_CHOICE, "Child", 10, CHILD_RATE},
  {SENIOR_CHOICE, "Senior", 30, SENIOR_RATE},
};
const unsigned int maximum_ticket_types =
    sizeof(ticket_info) / sizeof(ticket_info[0]);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < maximum_ticket_types; ++i)
{
    if (choice == ticket_info[i].choice)
    {
        summary(ticket_info[i].type_name,
                months,
                ticket_info[i].price,
                ticket_info[i].rate * months);
        break;
    }
}
```

This has the advantage that you can test it with only 1 entry and then add additional entries without adding additional code.

**Object Oriented**
In the Object Oriented approach, you would have either a ticket object (like the structure above) or have Parent Ticket and child ticket objects.  The objects would contain methods for printing a summary.
Here is a sample:

```
class Ticket_Base
{
  public:
    friend std::ostream& operator>>(std::ostream& output, const Ticket_Base& ticket);
    double rate;
    double price;
    std::string type_name;
};

class Adult_Ticket : public Ticket_Base
{
  public:
    Adult_Ticket()
      : rate(ADULT_RATE), price(40), type_name("Adult");
};
```

The senior and child ticket classes would look the same as the adult ticket.

You could use the Factory Pattern to create tickets and a generic function to print the ticket summary.

Comment: wow! thats a lot to take in! Thanks for the input! I wish I would be able to use someething like this for the project, but unfortunately I must follow my instructors guidelines as far as using function prototypes and if else if structures. Thanks again though! I will definitely keep this in the back of my mind for future developing